# Apply function to dataframe-column (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing a column with some freely chosen "codes" (e.g. "abcde", "blablabla"). Because the data come from an online survey sometimes the users mistyped the code they were supposed to enter. For example they wrote "bacde" instead of "abcde".

```r
library(RecordLinkage)
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(code = c(rep("abcde", 20), "bbcde", "abccde", rep("efghi", 20), "efigh", "efghj"))
```

I wrote a function `correctCodes()`that returns the "corrected" code. It uses levenshtein-distance to calculate the similarity between two strings. A code will only be corrected if there are at least two "reference codes" and if similarity exceeds a certain threshold (.8)

```
# function that calculates similarity between two strings
mylevsim = function (str1, str2) {
  return(1 - (RecordLinkage::levenshteinDist(str1, str2)/max(nchar(str1), nchar(str2))))
}


# Function that returns the corrected code
correctCodes <- function(wrongCode) {

  wrongCode <- trimws(toupper(wrongCode))
  
  counts <- df %>% 
    mutate(code = trimws(toupper(code))) %>%
    group_by(code) %>%
    summarise(n = n(),
              Var2 = code,
              code = NULL) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(code))
  
expand.grid(trimws(toupper(df$code)), trimws(toupper(df$code)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(similarity = mylevsim(Var1, Var2)) %>%
    arrange(Var1, desc(similarity)) %>%
    left_join(counts, by = "Var2") %>%
    mutate(both = paste(Var1, Var2)) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(both),
           Var1 != Var2,
           Var1 == wrongCode,
           n > 2,
           similarity > .8) %>%
     filter(row_number()==1) %>%
     pull(Var2)
}
```

Now, this works fine if I call the function like this (the function returns "ABCDE"):

```r
correctCodes("abccde")  # returns ABCDE
correctCodes("bbcde")   # returns ABCDE
correctCodes("efghj")   # returns EFGHI
```

However, if I want to use it within `dplyr::mutate()` it doesn't work at all:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(code_corrected = correctCodes(code))
```

Comment: Your `correctCodes` function is referencing `df`, why would that be? Shouldn't it _just_ use the string you pass to it?

Comment: using the "wrong" code only you cannot tell how it should be corrected. that's why you need to lookup which codes within the dataframe are similar.

Comment: your function breaches scope, making reproducibility and troubleshooting particularly difficult. If you want it to consider candidate strings, _pass them explicitly_. Having a function silently assume that it can find something in an object that may or may not be in the calling environment is risky, especially using `df` where, if you don't define it, you will get an obscure error about closures (and not `'df' not found`). It's straight-forward functional programming, only let the function work with what was explicitly passed.

Comment: but if you need the function to see all of the `df` data, then why not pass all of `df` instead of a column from it?

Comment: from reading your code, it seems like you don't have a defined set of reference codes, it must be imputed from the data, is that right?  If so I suggest a two-step process - one to process the entire dataset and make a list of reference codes, then a second pass to mutate a new column and allocate each row to the corrected reference code.

Comment: No, the codes were given to the users. They just has to enter them correctly in the survey form. So nothing needs to be imputed. Most of them were entered correctly, so there are always some correct reference codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to vectorize the function:

```
vectorized_correctCodes <- Vectorize(correctCodes)


df %>%
  mutate(code_corrected = vectorized_correctCodes(code))

     code code_corrected
1   abcde               
2   abcde               
3   abcde               
4   abcde               
5   abcde               
6   abcde               
7   abcde               
8   abcde               
9   abcde               
10  abcde               
11  abcde               
12  abcde               
13  abcde               
14  abcde               
15  abcde               
16  abcde               
17  abcde               
18  abcde               
19  abcde               
20  abcde               
21  bbcde          ABCDE
22 abccde          ABCDE
23  efghi               
24  efghi               
25  efghi               
26  efghi               
27  efghi               
28  efghi               
29  efghi               
30  efghi               
31  efghi               
32  efghi               
33  efghi               
34  efghi               
35  efghi               
36  efghi               
37  efghi               
38  efghi               
39  efghi               
40  efghi               
41  efghi               
42  efghi               
43  efigh               
44  efghj          EFGHI
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three things stopping your code from working correctly at the moment:

1. `mutate` passes the whole column as a vector to the function, which can currently only take a single string.

```r
correctCodes(df$code)
#> character(0)
```

Using `rowwise()` ahead of `mutate` would work:

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(code_corrected = correctCodes(code))
```

But there are two further problems...

2. Passing a correct code doesn't work as `Var1 != Var2` drops that as an option in your filtering:

```r
correctCodes("abcde")
#> character(0)
```

3. Passing a super-wrong string doesn't work, as this one gives a score of 0.667 so doesn't pass the 0.8 threshold:

```r
correctCodes("efigh")
#> character(0)
```

If you build in a check for "code already correct" then this would bypass problem #2. Problem #3 may require a different solution though (or choose the highest scoring match?)

### Edit - possible edited function/call as one way of solving problem:

```r
correctCodes <- function(wrongCode) {
  
  wrongCode <- trimws(toupper(wrongCode))
  
  counts <- df %>% 
    mutate(code = trimws(toupper(code))) %>%
    count(code) %>%
    filter(n > 2) |> 
    rename(Var2 = code)
  
  right_codes <- counts |> 
    pull(Var2)

  if (wrongCode %in% right_codes) return(wrongCode)
  
  expand.grid(trimws(toupper(df$code)), trimws(toupper(df$code)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(similarity = mylevsim(Var1, Var2)) %>%
    arrange(Var1, desc(similarity)) %>%
    inner_join(counts, by = "Var2") %>%
    mutate(both = paste(Var1, Var2)) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(both),
           Var1 != Var2,
           Var1 == wrongCode) %>%
    arrange(desc(similarity)) %>%
    filter(row_number()==1) %>%
    pull(Var2)
} 

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(code_corrected = correctCodes(code))

#> # A tibble: 44 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    code  code_corrected
#>    <chr> <chr>         
#>  1 abcde ABCDE         
#>  2 abcde ABCDE         
#>  3 abcde ABCDE         
#>  4 abcde ABCDE         
#>  5 abcde ABCDE         
#>  6 abcde ABCDE         
#>  7 abcde ABCDE         
#>  8 abcde ABCDE         
#>  9 abcde ABCDE         
#> 10 abcde ABCDE         
#> # ℹ 34 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. As you solely depend on user input and you can assume that more people enter it correctly than wrong. I translated that in any entry > 2 we trust (feel free to change) and that means that the other ones we try to fix.

For that we split the data, then do a cartesian join and get all combinations we need to calculate the distance for. Then we check for 0.8 similarity and up and pick the best match if more than one was found. Then join your data back. for illustration I just added the column trusted and the similarity. So those you can fix your codes for.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringdist)

setDT(df)

# standardize your codes
df[, code := trimws(toupper(code))]

# split your data into trusted codes and those you want to "verify / fix"
trusted <- df[, .N, code][N > 2, code]
verify <- df[!code %in% trusted]

# do a cartesian join to get all combinations you want to calculate the distance
check <- verify[, .(trusted = unlist(trusted)), by = verify]

# calculate similarity, I used stringdist package here 
check <- check[, similarity := stringsim(code, trusted, "lv")][similarity >= 0.8][, .SD[which.max(similarity)], code]

# join back, from there you can change them if you like
check[df, on = c("code")]

# code trusted similarity
# 1:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 2:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 3:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 4:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 5:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 6:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 7:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 8:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 9:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 10:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 11:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 12:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 13:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 14:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 15:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 16:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 17:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 18:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 19:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 20:  ABCDE    <NA>         NA
# 21:  BBCDE   ABCDE    0.80000
# 22: ABCCDE   ABCDE    0.83333
# 23:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 24:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 25:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 26:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 27:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 28:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 29:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 30:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 31:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 32:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 33:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 34:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 35:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 36:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 37:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 38:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 39:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 40:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 41:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 42:  EFGHI    <NA>         NA
# 43:  EFIGH    <NA>         NA
# 44:  EFGHJ   EFGHI    0.80000
```